# How do I query an Azure storage table with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm not sure where exactly, but I've got the wrong idea somewhere with this.

I'm trying to, in a first instance, query an azure storage table using linq. But I can't work out how it's done. From looking at a variety of sources I have the following:

```
List<BlogViewModel> blogs = new List<BlogViewModel>();

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("BlogConnectionString"));
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable blogTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("BlogEntries");

try
{
   TableServiceContext tableServiceContext = tableClient.GetTableServiceContext();
   TableServiceQuery<BlogEntry> query = (from blog in blogTable.CreateQuery<BlogEntry>()
   select blog).AsTableServiceQuery<BlogEntry>(tableServiceContext);
   foreach (BlogEntry blog in query)
   {
      blogs.Add(new BlogViewModel { Body = blog.Body });
   }
}
catch { }
```

I probably had it closer before I messed around with it. Either that, or I'm misunderstanding what the TableService is. The following code did work for me, but I'm trying to switch it to using Linq instead.

```
List<BlogViewModel> blogs = new List<BlogViewModel>();

var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("BlogConnectionString"));
var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable blogTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("BlogEntries");

TableRequestOptions reqOptions = new TableRequestOptions()
{
   MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5),
   RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 3)
};
List<BlogEntry> lists;

try
{
   var query = new TableQuery<BlogEntry>();
   lists = blogTable.ExecuteQuery(query, reqOptions).ToList();

   foreach (BlogEntry blog in lists)
   {
      blogs.Add(new BlogViewModel { Body = blog.Body });
   }
}
catch { }
```

I've been unable to find a good solid example anywhere of what I should be doing. But from what I've been reading, it does suggest using Linq is possible. Any help or pointers appreciated. Thanks.

---

Slight update. The following is the syntax error I currently get on AsTableServiceQuery:

'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'AsTableServiceQuery' and no extension method 'AsTableServiceQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

However, I don't think this reflects the real issue, I think I have just got it put together wrong, just can't find a solid example anywhere that works.

Comment: what exactly is happening? are you getting error messages? no data?

Comment: @Igorek Sorry, I have updated with the error. However, I don't think the code is close enough to what it should be for the error to really mean anything.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

TableServiceContext is no longer needed in the new Table Service Layer of Azure Storage Client Library. For more information on this change, please see our blog post [Announcing Storage Client Library 2.1 RTM & CTP for Windows Phone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/09/07/announcing-storage-client-library-2-1-rtm.aspx).

Please make sure BlogEntry implements [ITableEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.itableentity?view=azure-dotnet) and then the following code should work just fine:

```
List<BlogViewModel> blogs = new List<BlogViewModel>();

CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable blogTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("BlogEntries");

try
{
    IEnumerable<BlogEntry> query = (from blog in blogTable.CreateQuery<BlogEntry>()
                                    select blog);
    foreach (BlogEntry blog in query)
    {
        blogs.Add(new BlogViewModel { Body = blog.Body });
    }
}
catch { }
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly the example I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: CreateQuery<T> isn't supported on Windows Phone.

Comment: What if our entity already inherits from another class? Is there any other option at all to do the query?

Comment: @Paul You just need to make sure your entity implements `ITableEntity` (it does not need to derive from concrete `TableEntity`)

Comment: i believe this answer is now obsolete: attempting to do this: `IEnumerable<Translation> query = (from blog in table.CreateQuery<Translation>()
                                            select blog);` and get this exception on `select blog` *cannot convert query expression to type ilist<string>*

Comment: As for .NET Core there's one important difference - according to https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/resources/samples/azure-cosmos-db-table-dotnet-getting-started/ Azure Tables have now the same NuGet as CosmosDB. 
Use that instead of WindowsAzure.Storage as it's missing for ex. CreateQuery methods.

Comment: Don't forget to put a  using System.Linq;   statement at the top :-)

Answer (score 17):

My current table storage repository does this:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression) 
{
    if (IsTableEmpty())
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    }
    else
    {
        return _cloudTable.CreateQuery<TEntity>().AsQueryable().Where(expression);
    }
}
```

My _`cloudTable` corresponds to your `blogTable`.

Comment: This save my Day :-) Nice!

Comment: Thanks very much, also saved my day !

Answer (score 1):

Based on previous answer, I've created extensions methods to support `First, FirstOrDefault, Single and SingleOrDefault`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides additional Linq support for the <see cref="TableQuery{TElement}"/> class. 
/// </summary>
public static class LinqToTableQueryExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the first element in a sequence.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements of source.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="tableQuery">A TableQuery{TSource} to return the first element of</param>
    public static TSource First<TSource>(this TableQuery<TSource> tableQuery) where TSource : ITableEntity
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<TSource>)tableQuery.Take(1)).First();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the first element in a sequence that satisfies a specified condition.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements of source.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="tableQuery">A TableQuery{TSource} to return the first element of</param>
    /// <param name="predicate">A function to test an element for a condition.</param>
    public static TSource First<TSource>(this TableQuery<TSource> tableQuery, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate) where TSource : ITableEntity
    {
        return tableQuery.Where(predicate).Take(1).First();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the first element of the sequence or a default value if no such element is found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements of source.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="tableQuery">A TableQuery{TSource} to return the first element of</param>
    public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this TableQuery<TSource> tableQuery) where TSource : ITableEntity
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<TSource>)tableQuery.Take(1)).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the first element of the sequence that satisfies a condition or a default value if no such element is found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements of source.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="tableQuery">A TableQuery{TSource} to return the first element of</param>
    /// <param name="predicate">A function to test an element for a condition.</param>
    public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this TableQuery<TSource> tableQuery, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate) where TSource : ITableEntity
    {
        return tableQuery.Where(predicate).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is no exactly one element in the sequence.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements of source.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="tableQuery">A TableQuery{TSource}> to return the single element of</param>
    /// <param name="predicate">A function to test an element for a condition.</param>
    public static TSource Single<TSource>(this TableQuery<TSource> tableQuery, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate) where TSource : ITableEntity
    {
        // Get 2 and try to get single ^^
        return tableQuery.Where(predicate).Take(2).Single();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements of source.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="tableQuery">A TableQuery{TSource}> to return the single element of</param>
    /// <param name="predicate">A function to test an element for a condition.</param>
    public static TSource SingleOrDefault<TSource>(this TableQuery<TSource> tableQuery, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate) where TSource : ITableEntity
    {
        // Get 2 and try to get single ^^
        return tableQuery.Where(predicate).Take(2).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

So you can use it like that:

```
public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity { public string Email { get; set; } } 
...
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse( "MyStorageAccountConnectionstring");
var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("myTable");

// Linq Query with Where And First
var person = table.CreateQuery<CustomerEntity>()
    .Where(c => c.Email == "Walter1@contoso.com").First();

// Linq query that used the First() Extension method
person = table.CreateQuery<CustomerEntity>()
    .First(c => c.Email == "Walter1@contoso.com");
```

Comment: What's the intended use of this? `TableQuery` doesn't contain any data, and must be executed using `CloudTable.Execute(query)` or similar method. `First*()` & `Single*()` will return non-queryables which cannot be passed to `Execute()`.

Comment: @JoeBrockhaus, I've edited my answer to show how to use these extension methods.

Comment: I see, the verbiage in the CreateQuery method makes it seem like you must explicitly call one of the Execute methods. It's pretty annoying only part of the IQueryable interface is supported, and it's not clear which at compile time :-/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some handy extension methods to wrap this.. 
(and a bonus case for ServiceBus Custom Properties keystore)

```
namespace Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table
{
    public static class CloudTableExtensions
    {
        public static TEntity GetTableEntity<TEntity>(this CloudTable cloudTable, BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage, string partitionKeyPropertyName, string rowKeyPropertyName, TableRequestOptions requestOptions = null, OperationContext operationContext = null)
            where TEntity : ITableEntity, new()
        {
            var partitionKey = brokeredMessage.Properties[partitionKeyPropertyName] as string;
            var rowKey = brokeredMessage.Properties[rowKeyPropertyName] as string;
            return GetTableEntity<TEntity>(cloudTable, partitionKey, rowKey, requestOptions, operationContext);
        }

        public static TEntity GetTableEntity<TEntity>(this CloudTable cloudTable, string partitionKey, string rowKey, TableRequestOptions requestOptions = null, OperationContext operationContext = null)
            where TEntity : ITableEntity, new()
        {
            var singleInstanceQuery = (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)(x => x.PartitionKey == partitionKey && x.RowKey == rowKey);
            IEnumerable<TEntity> queryResults = cloudTable.ExecuteQuery(singleInstanceQuery, requestOptions, operationContext);
            return queryResults.SingleOrDefault();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TEntity> ExecuteQuery<TEntity>(this CloudTable cloudTable, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression, TableRequestOptions requestOptions = null, OperationContext operationContext = null)
            where TEntity : ITableEntity, new()
        {
            var query = cloudTable.CreateQuery<TEntity>().Where(expression) as TableQuery<TEntity>;
            return cloudTable.ExecuteQuery(query, requestOptions, operationContext);
        }
    }
}
```